# error with import <cocoa/cocoa.h>

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I added class files from another project to my new iPhone Window for the first time.   The class is a simple class that defines a polygon, and subclasses NSObject.   As part of the standard template for an Objective C class, this class definition imports Cocoa.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

However, just by adding this class, I'm getting an error that

```
Cocoa/Cocoa.h:No such file or directory.
```

I don't understand this because the exact same line occurs in another class definition (the controller) within the same project.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong about another class importing cocoa.h.   Is it because on the iPhone you can't import cocoa.h and have to use UIKit?  the original Polygon class was for a foundation tool...

Comment: Or should I be importing 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Subclasses of NSObject (at least on the iPhone) do not import the Cocoa.h header. Instead, they import Foundation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Answer (score 7):

On the iPhone you generally use UIKit instead of Cocoa, which is for Mac OS X.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

You might import just the Foundation framework in a model class that doesn't reference any user interface stuff.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you generate a NSManagedObject subclass out of your datamodel (in an iPhone project), I assume in later versions of XCode this will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Project Target->"Build Settings"->"Base SDK", then select "Latest OS X(OS X 10.x)"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem occur when I accidentally overwrote the testApp-Prefix.pch code.

This then deleted the code adding #import  (as mentioned above)

Once I noticed and undid the error disappeared