# How to execute a downloaded iphone app having <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> framework

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance .

I have downloaded an iphone app. It has imported

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

like this. when i try to build the app is not building.It is giving an error

> /Users/apple/Downloads/downloaded
>   apps/CoreAnimation/CoreAnimation_Prefix.pch:6:0
>   /Users/apple/Downloads/downloaded
>   apps/CoreAnimation/CoreAnimation_Prefix.pch:6:28:
>   error: Cocoa/Cocoa.h: No such file or
>   directory.

If any one know please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error with import <cocoa/cocoa.h>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745548/error-with-import-cocoa-cocoa-h)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's an iPhone app, and I doubt that this will be the last problem you're encountering, but you can do something like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #else
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
  #endif
#endif
```